# Make a copy of JPanel Using Netbeans 6.9

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Alright I am using the Desktop Application for making a swing program and I have a JPanel in a TabbedPane that I would like to copy the JPanel to another tab. Just using the = makes it so when I change one I change both. Is there a way to make a copy of the JPanel and be able to customize the second one without actually changing the first one

Answer (score 0):

1) Open the form containing the panel in design mode
2) Open the inspector Window (Window > Navigating > Inspector)
3) Select the panel in the inspector window
4) Right-click copy, then paste where you want the copy